# Problem with INNER JOIN in a VIEW

Tags: sql-server

I need a view that Show each Location(including prénom_Nom, numéro_Teléphone, niv,no_Modèle,  année) and all Paiements. Finally order by id_Location.

I try this but its not Work

```
CREATE View On_locations_Clients_Paiements AS

SelectClients.prénom_Nom,Clients.numéro_Teléphone,Véhicules.niv,Véhicules.no_Modèle,
Véhicules.année,Paiements.montant

FROM Location
INNER JOIN Location ON Clients.id_Client=Location.id_Client
INNER JOIN Véhicules ON Location.niv=Véhicules.niv
INNER JOIN  Modèle ON Véhicules.no_Modèle=Modèle.no_Modèle
INNER JOIN Paiements ON Location.id_Location = Paiements.id_Location 



--ORDER BY where id_Location = id_Location
```

This is the select  (I'm not sure if its right)

```
CREATE View On_locations_Clients_Paiements AS

Select Clients.prénom_Nom,Clients.numéro_Teléphone,Véhicules.niv,Véhicules.no_Modèle,Véhicules.année,Paiements.montant
```

Those are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
  PK[id_Location] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[debut_Location] [datetime] NULL,
[premier_Paiement] [datetime] NULL,
[paiment_Mensuel] [smallmoney] NULL,
[nombre_Mensualité] [char](2) NULL,
  FK[id_Client] [char](6) NULL,
[no_Termes_location] [char](6) NULL,
  FK[niv] [char](20) NULL,


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
  PK[id_Client] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[prénom_Nom] [varchar](50) NULL,
[adresse] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ville] [varchar](20) NULL,
[province] [varchar](20) NULL,
[code_Postal] [char](6) NULL,
[numéro_Teléphone] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Véhicules](
  PK[niv] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[no_Modèle] [char](6) NULL,
[année] [char](4) NULL,
[kilométrage] [int] NULL,
[location_Antérieure] [char](3) NULL,
[valeur] [smallmoney] NULL,
[tranmission_Automatique] [char](3) NULL,
[airClimatise] [char](3) NULL,
[antiDemarreur] [char](3) NULL,
[no_Couleur] [char](6) NULL,

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Paiements](
  PK[id_paiement] [char](6) NOT NULL,
[date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[montant] [smallmoney] NULL,
  FK[id_Location] [char](6) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get results back, are they incorrect, does it give you an error?\

Comment: Msg 1013, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure On_locations_Clients_Paiements, Ligne 5
The objects "Location" and "Location" in the clause FROM have the sames names exposed. Use name of  correlation for distinguish.

Comment: Its wired because  i give the extended name....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the second location out and the tables:

```
CREATE View On_locations_Clients_Paiements AS

Select c.prénom_Nom
      ,c.numéro_Teléphone
      ,v.niv
      ,v.no_Modèle
      ,v.année
      ,p.montant
FROM Location AS l
INNER JOIN Clients AS c ON c.id_Client=l.id_Client
INNER JOIN Véhicules AS v ON l.niv=v.niv
INNER JOIN  Modèle AS m ON v.no_Modèle=m.no_Modèle
INNER JOIN Paiements AS p ON l.id_Location = p.id_Location
```

Comment: You can't use an `ORDER BY` in a view. You need to order the results you `SELECT` from the view. If you need to include a column from `Location`, just add that column to the `SELECT` in the view (obviously prefixed by the alias `l`.

Comment: I have a problem they return just the client they make payment. Its suppose to give me all the location for each client and paiment if its the case

Comment: Why are you putting ORDER BY in a view?

Comment: Because i'm  a beginner sorry

Comment: Thank's Wil your response is realy useful

Comment: If they don't all have Payments you want a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: @HLGEM, yes I missed that part. Definitely change the last `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` if it's not required they have a payment.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
FROM Location
INNER JOIN Location ON Clients.id_Client=Location.id_Client
```

to...

```
FROM Location
INNER JOIN Clients ON Clients.id_Client=Location.id_Client
```

Updated - you are referencing `Location` twice and `Clients` never so I think you have a copy/paste error of some sort.

Comment: That won't work because he never `SELECTED` from `Clients` in the first place.